# How download files on app mobile with PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: ios, file, download, phpspreadsheet

for my project I'm using PHPSpreadsheet for exporting data in Excel and PDF format.
If from the website, when I press on the respective download buttons, I can easily download the .xlsx and .pdf files, I have problems with the app (iOs Swift language). In fact, when I try to download the files, I receive the following messages:

- for Excel files: "the file may be damaged"
- for PDF files (I open it with Chrome): "Chrome does not support this link file: ///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/name_file.pdf"

Here are the fragments of the PHP code that deal with the download:

PDF:

```
$ output. = '... html code';
$ mpdf = new \ Mpdf \ Mpdf ();
$ mpdf-> Bookmark ('Start of the document');
$ Mpdf-> WriteHTML ($ output);
$ mpdf-> Output ($ filename.'. pdf', 
\Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD);
```

EXCEL:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();  /*----Spreadsheet object-----*/
$Excel_writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);  /*----- Excel (Xls) Object*/

/* ...riempiendo foglio excel con i dati */

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: 
attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$Excel_writer->save('php://output');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> for Excel files: "the file may be damaged"

My blind guess is that when you peek the file content you will find `Headers already sent` PHP message polluting your file. If that is so, just call [ob_start()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before you call any of your `header()`s.